# How to get video duration by youtube-dl in python?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get youtube video duration by using youtube-dl in python.
here is the code, I cant find duration in dictMeta, how to get it?

```
    import youtube_dl

    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'tmp/%(id)s.%(ext)s',
    'noplaylist': True,
    'quiet': True,
    'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'audioformat': 'wav',
    'forceduration':True
}
sID = "t99ULJjCsaM"
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    dictMeta = ydl.extract_info(
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={sID}".format(sID=sID),
        download=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just simple

```
dictMeta['duration']
```

Comment: Does youtube-dl provides us with durations in miliseconds or do we have to convert that ourselves?

Comment: For @keanu_reevers , how I find out. Video: Hank Green, vlogbrothers, "Honest YouTube Talk Time", CC Attribution License (reuse allowed); known video length: `00:03:56 = 236 seconds = 236000 ms` . Experiment time! **Experiment 1, interactive python prompt**: OP's code example, without `'logger': MyLogger(),`, with `sID = "cRWr4VNqIjY"`. (From python's interactive terminal, I actually get `3:56` returned, though I'm not sure from where.) Using the answer from Macio, INPUT: `>>>dictMeta['duration']` OUTPUT: `236`. **ANSWER**: `youtube-dl` DOESN'T provide us durations in ms; it provides seconds.

Comment: **Experiment 2, `bash` command-line version of youtube-dl**: INPUT: `$ youtube-dl --get-duration "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRWr4VNqIjY"` OUTPUT: `3:56`. Even more conversion will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think youtube_dl changes the result string by `extract_info`, now it should be: (If you use "ytsearch" for searching query on Youtube)

```
dictMeta['entries'][0]['duration']
```